# Wobble/Wiggle effect in Adobe Premiere Pro CC

Tags: premiere

Is there a way to add a “wiggle” to a keyframable value in Adobe Premiere Pro (CC)? For example, if I wanted an image to jitter back and forth, I could apply such an effect to the rotation value.

There is such an effect in Adobe After Effects: by adding an expression to a value, and typing `wiggle(frequency, amplitude, octaves, amplitude multiplier, time)` (with numbers instead of the arguments), the value will randomly shift up and down over time depending on what arguments you entered.

**tl;dr:** Is there a way to produce an effect in Premiere akin to the wiggle() expression in After Effects?

Comment: Not on vanilla Adobe premiere. Perhaps there is a plugin, but I wouldn't count on it since Premiere is more about cuts, than gfx.

Comment: Can you use Dynamic Linking to do this in After Effects? I realize it's not the cleanest, but if you are trying to produce this effect, it may be your only option. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

You could build a project in after effects (or get someone else who has AE to build it for you?)

Get them to set a wiggle using Expressions.
Convert the expression to keyframes using the Animation menu --> Keyfraem Assistant --> convert to expression to keyframes.

Save the layer as an Essential Graphics template.

Open the Essential Graphics template in Premiere.

The item will have the positional wiggle, but you won't be able to modify the wiggle, or parent anything else to it (the positional variable in Premiere won't be wiggling).

I'm not sure whether this will work if you do not have AE installed - someone would have to try it and see).

Answer (score 0):

I thought the same thing as @tomh.

Although, I might have another idea:

After Effects has a specific window called `Wiggler` and it allows you to create a wiggle movement based on keyframes (instead of using a script), this way you could copy the keyframes made in AE to your PP position property.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free Wiggler effect that works on PPro. https://www.prosya.com/software/wiggler-effect/

The entire wiggle function  `wiggle(frequency, amplitude, octaves, amplitude multiplier, time)` is implemented as effect params.